# Strange: Cant get '1' from Math.random

Tags: java

I am using the following code, it generates numbers randomly but the problem is, I am not able to figure out why does not it generate the number `1`

```
        int ran, g, d, col, ran2;
        double y = 1000 * (Double.parseDouble(t2.getText()));
        int x = (int) y;
        d = Integer.parseInt(anum.getText());
        double c = 10;
        int prevrandom = Integer.parseInt(lnum.getText());
        lnum.setText("");
        lnum.setVisible(true);
        for (g = 0; g==0;) {
            d = Integer.parseInt(anum.getText());
            ran = (int) (Math.random() * (c)); // Random Number Creation Starts
            if (ran > (c / 10)) {
                g = 1;
                ran2 = ((int) (Math.random() * 10)) % 2;
                if (ran2 == 1) {
                    ran = ran * (-1);
                }
                d = d + ran;
                if (d < 0) {
                    ran = ran * (-1);
                    d = d + (2 * ran);
                }
                int a = d - ran;
                if(prevrandom==ran){
                    g=0;
                }
                if(g==1){
                    lnum.setText("" + ran);
                }
            }
        }
```

I call this function(button) from somewhere. The problem comes when the sum ('a') becomes 4, according to my conditions it shouldn't allow any number other than 'one' and thus it goes into infinite loop.

I am talking about `ran` variable. Which I get after multiplying `Math.random` with `10^x` where `x` is a positive integer.

Here `ran2` is a number with value 1 or 0. As I multiply Math.Random with 10 which gives a 1 digit number and I mod it with 2.

THis is a 14 year old boy new to java. it would be greatful of people out here to help rather than discourage.

Comment: You've provided *far* more code than is really required here, including user input which you haven't specified. Please reduce this to *just* the relevant code.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir i thought maybe problem is not where i tell u. Therefore i decided to give the whole code

Comment: `Math.random()` generates a number 0.0 <= x < 1.0...

Comment: @DakshShah If you cut down the code and the problem still occures then the problem is in that part of the code

Comment: What exactly is this code trying to achieve?

Comment: This code is borderline unreadable. At least replace your `if ||` "antipattern" with if `ran >= ... && ran <= ...`

Comment: `ran2 = ((int) (Math.random() * 10)) % 2;` is the same as `Math.random() < 0.5`  There is too much crazy code for me, I suggest you step through your code in a debugger and try to remove half of it.

Comment: I would assume it is broken unless you understand it. Can you demonstrate why it should become `1`? If you can't do that, you have to assume its too complicated.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I might be missing something but wouldn't `Math.random() < 0.5` be a boolean and `ran2 = ((int) (Math.random() * 10)) % 2;` be a number?

Comment: "Here ran2 is a number with value 1 or 0 as i multiply Math.Random with 10 which gives a 1 digit number and i mod it with 2" why do you do that, if you just want a random 0 or 1 there are vastly easier ways to do it

Comment: @RichardTingle Sir i get your point But can you please tell me why is it giving error? You are telling me ways to improve what already is working

Comment: @DakshShah But what is it supposed to do? If its just supposed to give random numbers in a range then that could be replaced with a single line

Comment: @RichardTingle correct but this is used only as `if(ran2 == 1)` which is a boolean.

Comment: We're not trying to discourage you, we're trying to get the information we need to answer this question; **what this code is supposed to do**

Comment: @RichardTingle Sir i took this as a discouragement only because people just keep on click vote down and i feel as if i should'nt have had asked. Anyways i figured out the problem. Thanks for helping Richard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the code

```
 if (ran > (c / 10)) {
```

The random number gets created which is even equal to one; but here due to the sign '>' it gets rejected.
Use '>=' instead.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29):

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to
>   0.0 and **less than 1.0**. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

If you need integer random numbers, you might be better off with [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). To generate a random integer in the range  `a..b` (inclusively), you can use

```
Random random=new Random();
int rnd=a+random.nextInt(b-a+1);
```

Comment: Sir i am talking bout 'ran' variable

Comment: ran = (int) (Math.random() * (c)); where c is from 10 to 10^x

Comment: @DakshShah You need to explain what your code is supposed to do if we are to figure that out (also, its not nessissary to call everyone sir)

Comment: @DakshShah The line is fine, it's you assumption your don't get `1` which is incorrect. See my answer.

Comment: If c=10, ran should become 1 for any random number >=0.1 and <0.2. For c=100, ran becomes 1 for any random number >=0.01 and <0.02. And so on. I'm pretty sure random numbers in these ranges occur quite frequently (in 1/9 of all cases), so the problem must be elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

> ran = (int) (Math.random() * (c)); where c is from 10 to 10^x

This can be 1 as follows.

```
int c = 1000;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    int ran;
    do {
        ran = (int) (Math.random() * (c)); // where c is from 10 to 10^x
        count++;
    } while (ran != 1);
    System.out.println("count: " + count);
}
```

prints sometime like

```
count: 1756
count: 86
count: 839
count: 542
count: 365
....
count: 37
count: 2100
count: 825
count: 728
count: 1444
count: 1943
```

It returns `1` a thousand time in less than a second.

Comment: Sir can you please point out what is wrong in my existing code?

Comment: @DakshShah Apart from the code being unreadable, you have to demonstrate what is wrong, it is your question.  The code is fine for me. ;)

Comment: @DakshShah You have to say what it should do and what it does do.  You should also give code which allows others to reproduce your problem so we can fix it.  I strongly suggest you step through your code in a debugger so you understand what you have written.